# posting data from java to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

I am trying to link java to a mysql database.

When I write data from my app the data does not show on my database.

Here's the error:

```
E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: From which programming language are you trying to connect to mysql? Also, please give us the relevant class in a code snipped. It looks like you got NullPointerException on a function that is trying to get the size of a folder.

Comment: I use java language

Comment: can you edit your message and upload your code please?